# Custom MessageBox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am making a custom MessageBox in my own language (Persian). I want to know which component may I use for the text?

Label is not multiline and TextBox is a little bit not appropriate.
Which component does Visual Studio use itself?

[image: The Visual Studio MessageBox]

What is the component I specified in the picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I support the answer of RQDQ, labels could be enlarged to occupy more than one line.
They have a property named TextAlign. When set to LeftCenter or MiddleCenter you could simulate the behavior of text in a message box. If the text doesn't fit in a single line, the label wraps it  automatically on another line. However in this case I will let the property AutoSize to its false default value.

Comment: I didn't get the answer Dear Steve.
the MiddleCenter doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using a System.Windows.Forms.Label with TextAlign property set to MiddleCenter right?   Do you resize your label **at design time** to show more than one line?   Not at runtime with AutoSize=true.

Comment: Thanks, It works.
by the way, do you what is the component I specified in the red box?

Comment: If that is the output of a MessageBox.Show() then it's not a component. It's an internal window with special flags (If my ancient memories of Windows C SDK programming are not failing me)

Comment: about That MiddleCenter trick, does it work on run time? (with AutoSize = false;).
I'm trying but I don't get the answer.

Comment: Sure, why not?. But you don't need to do anything at runtime (of course if you use the label created during design). Put only your multiword text in the label text property.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a label.  It has a number of options for laying out the text... One way is to set it to "AutoSize = True".

Comment: Thank you, But seems to me the Label does not have word wrap functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what kind of Visual Studio project you are doing.  Wpf or Silverlight or Asp.net or even windows, everything will depend upon which kind of project it is.

That looks to me like the MFC style label with an image, or in a browser it would be done with javascript.

Comment: I am using Windows Form project.

Comment: Because you are using the Win Form App, you are going to need to create a custom form (window) for this and be able to use it globally by doing creating an instance of the form, set the custom message into the form, then DoModal.  You will probably want to do a multiline text box, with overridden style properties so it does not show the boundries OR  you can use the MessageBox option and manually add the \n  so it will break into new lines for you.

Comment: MessageBox.Show("This is going to \n break a new line.");

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use RichTextBox. I Use it For My Custom MessageBox And it works Correctlly